# Discrete probability example

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Adapted from example 6.5.5 from Discrete Mathematics by Richard Johnsonbaough: Match six distinct numbers, in any order, among numbers 1-52. What's the probability of winning?

I get why the solution is $\frac{1}{C(52,6)}$, but I don't quite understand why my initial attempt is wrong:

$$\frac{1}{52} \times \frac{1}{51} \times \frac{1}{50} \times \frac{1}{49} \times \frac{1}{48} \times \frac{1}{47}$$.

I first select one card from 52, then one from 51, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your attempt implies that the order of the cards *does* matter, but the problem says it does not. When drawing the first card, you have 6 options for success out of the deck of 52 cards, not only 1. On your second pick, there are 5 of the remaining 51 that are allowed, and so on. You approach assumes that each particular card needs to be matched to the correct slot, i.e., that the order matters.

Comment: Thanks, how lovely. I have checked that this is indeed true. $\frac{1}{C(52,6)} = 6/52 * 5/51 * 4/50 * 3/49 * 2/48 * 1/ 47$